# Is there a C++ cross platform USB library?

Tags: c++, usb, cross-platform

I'm (going to be) writing an application in Qt that will run on the 3 main OSes (Windows, Linux and Mac). One of the features of this app is that it needs USB to talk to a piece of custom external hardware. Is there a cross-platform USB library available?

Comment: Does the custom hardware speak HID over USB, or use the serial line directly?

Comment: Probably a serial link. It's an ATMega USB chip, with the LUFA USB library, which has support for both but a serial link is probably the most likely option.

Comment: Ahh, but on Windows you can find a dozen-and-a-half third-party libraries for $$$ ;-)

Comment: @pst ONLY $$$? Nice! That's plenty much good value! I'll have to buy some of those pronto! Wait... ;P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/).

> Supported operating systems: Linux,
>   FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin,
>   MacOS X (and Windows, through the
>   libusb-win32 project).

<strike>But you should note that it uses `libusb0.sys` kernel-mode driver on Windows, which is not WHQL certified and it could be a problem in 64-bit Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.</strike> Sorry, version 1.2.0.0 of `libusb0.sys` [is digitally signed](http://www.libusb.org/ticket/49).

Comment: Thank you! Just the info I needed.

Comment: The problem with using libusb-win32 is that it's a port of libusb-0.1, which isn't compatible with libusb-1.0.  However libusb-1.0 now appears to support Windows natively.

Comment: Libusb has gotten better in recent years: you can now use it on Windows to talk to devices that have WinUSB as their driver, so you don't have to run any kernel mode code from third parties like `libusb0.sys`.

Comment: Unfortunately libusb's support for composite devices on Windows is basically non-existent.

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to update this post for anyone who is coming back to it nowadays...

Libusb (version 0.1) has since been deprecated. The modern standard is to use libusb-1.0 or libusbx.

Personally, I think there are many reasons to use libusbx. It was written by frustrated libusb-0.1 developers who wanted a more frequent update cycle and better bug maintenance system.

My reasons for suggesting libusbx are as follows:

- does not require sudo access
- worked much better for me out of the box with reading incoming messages
- better support and more frequent responses to bugs/issues
- async and synchronous support for sending/receiving messages

Granted, libusb-1.0 does support async/sync reporting... but the philosophy behind libusbx is much more appealing and the documentation is better.

So it's totally up to you, if you or whoever would still like to know some more about the libraries, the history is very easy to find online. You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679480/details-on-usb-no-luck-so-far/17679571#17679571) stack question for some more info on the immediate subject.

Comment: As of February 2014, there is actually only [libusb](http://libusb.info) remaining. The linusbx homepage has the following comment:
libusbx was a fork of [libusb](http://libusb.info), a library that provides generic access to USB devices.
As of 2014.01.26, this project has been fully merged back into [libusb](http://libusb.info) and is being discontinued.
Since there will be no further releases of libusbx, you are strongly encouraged to switch to using [libusb](http://libusb.info).

Comment: Libusbx is no longer maintained.You should use libusb instead.

Comment: I recommend removing the old libusbx link, it now hosts a site not safe for work,